# Codename one IOS builds failing

Tags: ios, codenameone

I have been having issues with IOS debug and release builds on the codename one server. From the build server I get the following output:

```
 error: Provisioning profile "org.ims.xconnect IOS_DEVELOPMENT Profile" doesn't match the entitlements file's values for the application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements. (in target 'XConnect' from project 'XConnect')
```

I tried regenerating the certificates using CN1's IOS wizard, for the project I'm working on and an entirely new project, but I keep running into this error.

I tried manually creating the certificates and profiles using Apple's developer website and adding them to the CN1 project, but then I require a password which I don't set anywhere, I also can't find the passwords on Apple's website.

I also tried changing the xCode version with the hopes that that might work.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll need to see the full error log to help. This is the final error but there are many hints along the way about what went wrong. The best approach for solving these sort of failures is to paste a link to the full error log to the chat widget on our website.

The most common failure is when people change the package name or main class name of their app without changing them everywhere (in codenameone_settings.properties etc.).

Comment: Thanks, Shai. I needed to add my developer ID to the codename1.ios.appid setting. This is done automatically with your latest update. Thanks for the great support